# How to version lock packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, aptitude

On CentOS exists the `yum versionlock` option, where you can lock a package to a specific version, so it is never upgraded past that.

I would like that

```
puppet-server-2.7.19-1
puppet-2.7.19-1
```

stays on 2.7, and never upgraded to 3.0. Puppet Labs have released 3.0 and put it into the stable repo, so 2.7 will get upgraded to 3.0, which is not backwards compatible.

Does Ubuntu have something similar to `yum versionlock`?

Comment: `sudo apt-mark hold <package name>` works for me (it holds the package at the current version)

Comment: Simplest answer is the one in Janakas comment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences` and pin packages' version.

The format for the file would be somewhat like this:

```
Package: puppet-server
Pin: version 2.7*
Pin-Priority: 550
```

---

See also:

- [Debian documentation | Apt Howto](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html)
- [Debian Wiki | Apt preferences](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-apt.2BAC8-preferences)
- [`manpage of apt_preferences`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)

Comment: Note if there is no star at the end of the pin version, it will go for latest! . Or you have to find the exact ubuntu numenclature, something like 2.7.1-00.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
aptitude hold puppet-server puppet
echo "puppet-server hold" | dpkg --set-selections
echo "puppet hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: `hold` will keep the package at the current version, and not let it upgrade any further. I would like it to upgrade to any 2.7.x but not 3.x.x